# wrong zend framework installation on ubuntu

Tags: zend-framework, ubuntu, installation

I have installed the zend framework on ubuntu 8.04 by [this](http://digitizor.com/2010/03/03/how-to-install-zend-framework-1-10-2-in-ubuntu/) article. and found that it is the 1.5 version of zf , but i want to install version 1.11. now how can i do that .

I think  first i need to uninstall the old version. and then install new version.
oops i was forget to run command `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: @piddl0r: & @Rahul: , why bother ? chances are when you upload to a production server they whont install it thru PEAR nor distro packages , you can just download the framework from zend and use it as you would with any other framework . the only difference would be you don't get the command line utility using this but realy it's not that big of a deal .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jeremy Kendall](http://twitter.com/jeremykendall) has a great post on his blog about setting up ZF on Ubuntu:

[From Zero to Zend Framework Project in 10 Minutes](http://www.jeremykendall.net/2010/04/17/from-zero-to-zend-framework-project-in-10-minutes/)

It discusses file locations, symlinking, virtual hosts, and even gets the ZF command-line tool working with .bash_aliases. Very clear, very straightforward.